# MediaElement can't play network paths containing a #

Tags: wpf, windows

My `F:\` drive is a mapped network drive.
I have two videos on it:

```
F:\Video1.mp4
F:\Video#1.mp4
```

I'd like to use a `MediaElement` to play them.

```
<MediaElement Source="F:\Video1.mp4" />  <!-- works -->
<MediaElement Source="F:\Video#1.mp4" />  <!-- doesn't work -->
```

It seems the `#` is being treated as `%23` when it is a network path.  This works fine if `F:\` is a local drive.

How can I make `F:\Video#1.mp4` work?  It is a legitimate path.

Comment: Is your uri really hardcoded ? If yes why not move them to a static class and do a `{x:Static local:MyConstants.VideoUri}` ?

Comment: no, my URI's are fed in dynamically, i have no control over them.  making the path a static resource doesn't change anything anyways.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Try creating a URI with `file:///` prepended:

```
mediaElement.Source = new Uri( "file:///" + @"F:\Video#1.mp4" );
```

This [Social post](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/62bcc099-259f-4222-a13e-917c2f9f2de9/systemwindowscontrolsmediaelement-doesnt-support-filenames-with-in-the-filename-eg-screen?forum=wpf) says that worked for them.